# Convert consecutive time difference (timedelta) to seconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timedelta

I calculated my consecutive time difference in my DataFrame of `d` using:

```
d['delta'] = (d['time'] - d['time'].shift()).fillna(0)
```

So I have the time difference in 'delta' column. My question is how can I convert that to seconds? The output is in the format of 00:50:00, I want to convert that to 3000 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Your column is of timedelta64 type so you can use the `.dt` accessor to find the `seconds` property:

```
d['delta'].dt.seconds
```

More information about the `.dt` accessor can be found [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor).

---

As @Jeff points out in the comments, you're likely to be better off using `total_seconds()` instead of `seconds`; the latter only returns whole (integer) numbers of seconds (*modulo* 1 day == 86400 seconds) whereas the former will return float values, counting smaller units of time (ms, ns) as well as days towards the value:

```
d['delta'].dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using (`pd.__version__`)?

Comment: That's a very old version of pandas. The `.dt` accessor was introduced in about 0.15. The current release is 0.17 - I strongly recommend that you upgrade to that because of the numerous enhancements and bug fixes that have been made.

Comment: I am trying to upgrade it

Comment: and you actually want to do a frequency conversion, e.g. ``d['delta'].dt.total_seconds()`` or ``d['delta'].astype('timedelta64[s]')``, see docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion)

Comment: @ajcr, ``.dt.seconds`` returns the number of seconds, not including fractions and less than 1 day, as this is what ``datetime.timedelta`` does., e.g. ``Timedelta("1 day 10 min 1 seconds").seconds == 601``. Personally I find this confusing, but more confusing to do something different than the built-ins.

Comment: @Jeff: thanks for the clarification and additional info - good to know the rationale behind the methods.